# Size of "guid" for 1000 samples - chance of conflict/duplicate?

Tags: probability, guid

Guids are unique for all intents & purposes, but I need a shorter code that is easier to remember / write down for a study of approximately 1000-1500 samples. What length code should I use, assuming it's A-Z or 1-9 in any digit? i.e. how long must the code be for the chance of a collision to be statistically insignificant? (or as insignificant as a GUID).

The codes will be generated for patients on different devices, so they need to be random and as short as possible for recording on different documents. They will be generated by Javascript in an Html webpage, although the device will potentially be offline at the time.

Comment: Do they actually need to be random? Could you just do 0000, 0001, 0002 etc?

Comment: They need to be random, they will be generated by different devices.

Comment: Do the devices have any identifier that you could use (or assign) as a prefix?

Comment: No, it's going to be generated in a webpage. We're considering using the first 3 chars of the surname, but since the numbers are relatively small (< 1500), I suspect it might make the code even longer.

Comment: If it's going to be generated on a web page, doesn't that suggest it could be generated by a single server? (It would really help if you'd give more context here...)

Comment: *Guids are unique for all intents & purposes*  No, they're not.  They're not *guaranteed* to be unique.  The probability of collision is extremely small, but it's *not* zero, even under perfectly random generation - which your computer doesn't really do.  If they're going to be used "for patients on different devices", the consequences of collision might be significant.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry. It's done by a webpage but in an offline environment, so it won't be connected to the server.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm using "for all intents and purposes" to mean "practically speaking", which I believe is acceptable & correct.